# Dropped File only moves one bit then exception

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, shapes, pane

So I asked a question about drag and drop last time and thanks to the help I almost got the hang of it. My problem ist after I dragged my rectangle from the left Anchorpane to the right pane, if I try to grab it in the second pane it will only move a few milimeters before showing an InvocationTargetException. Thats my code:

```
public void smthOver(DragEvent de) {
    if (de.getGestureSource() == rect || de.getGestureSource() == ovalo || de.getGestureSource() == strich) {
        de.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
        de.consume();         
    } else {
        de.acceptTransferModes();
    }

public void smthDropped(DragEvent de) {
    if (de.getGestureSource() == rect) {
        dropZone.getChildren().add(rect);
        de.consume();
    } else if (de.getGestureSource() == ovalo) {
        dropZone.getChildren().add(ovalo);
        de.consume();
    } else if (de.getGestureSource() == strich) {
        dropZone.getChildren().add(strich);
        de.consume();
    }

}

public void smthDetectedRect(MouseEvent me) {
    try {
        Dragboard db = rect.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(rect.getId());
        db.setContent(content);
        me.consume();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}

public void smthPressedRect(MouseEvent me) {
    x = me.getSceneX();
    y = me.getSceneY();
    orgTranslateX = ((Rectangle) (me.getSource())).getTranslateX();
    orgTranslateY = ((Rectangle) (me.getSource())).getTranslateY();
    rect.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
}

public void smthDraggedRect(MouseEvent me) {
    double offsetX = me.getSceneX() - x;
    double offsetY = me.getSceneY() - y;
    double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
    double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

    ((Rectangle) (me.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
    ((Rectangle) (me.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry didnt know i have to show the stacktrace

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent 
   = Pane[id=dropZone]
```

So I understand the exception that I add multiple children with the name "rect" to the Pane in "smthDropped" but you have any Idea how I can fix this? Because I use "smthDropped" to add the Shape from the left pane to the right. Hope this solves the confusion

Comment: If you could post your code where you call the functions, that would make it more helpful to see how the logic is flowing

Comment: Please include your stack trace. `InvocationTargetException` may not be the only issue.

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is often an exception that wraps the real issue in it's `cause`. The full stacktrace should contain this kind of information. It would make spotting the issue much easier. Please [edit] the question and include the complete stack trace in a code block.

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the tip I edited the question now with the Stacktrace